# Scraping a page to retrieve prices, currency code messing things up

Tags: web-scraping, preg-replace

I'm scraping a page using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser and I want to retrieve the price. It's been going well except for a page that I've encountered, where the html reads:

```
<p class="was-price">Was: &#163;220.00</p>
```

I want to scrape the part that reads 220.00 and I am very confused about how to retrieve it. Thus far I have been using `preg_replace()` with great success to strip out text from a string, yet this is the first time I have come across a currency symbol in numeric format.

Today is the first day I have used `preg_replace()` and it's confusing to say the least. Can it be used to remove currency symbols in this way? Or should I be looking at another method? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) to decode encoded html entities. Then you apply `preg_replace()`.

```
$str = '<p class="was-price">Was: &#163;220.00</p>';
$str = html_entity_decode($str);
echo $str; 
preg_replace(...);
```